# vertica with spring jdbc template

Tags: spring-jdbc, vertica

Hi im having trouble configuring a datasource to vertica (6.1.3) with spring (4.2.x).

getting this error..any ideas on what i am missing?  RefMetricMappingDao extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport.

```
<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${vertica.driver.classname}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${vertica.connection.string}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${vertica.connection.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${vertica.connection.password}"/>
</bean>


<bean name="refMetricMappingDao" class="RefMetricMappingDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
</bean>
```

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.vertica.jdbc.VerticaConnectionImpl.isValid(I)Z
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:918)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:283)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2307)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:680)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:707)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:250)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:257)
>       at

Answer (score 2):

duh...vertica comes with a datasource class

```
<bean id="dataSource2" class="com.vertica.jdbc.DataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="${vertica.connection.string}"/>
    <property name="userID" value="${vertica.connection.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${vertica.connection.password}"/>
    <property name="searchPath" value="${vertica.connection.schemaname}"/>
    <property name="batchInsertDirect" value="true"/>
</bean>
```